# Logstash config -- add field based off regex capturing group

Tags: regex, split, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

So, I have a hostname field that looks something like:

amma-pr-app-03.hst.hosting.com

I've made the following regex:

([^-]{4,5})-(pr|st)-(app|svc|srv)-(\d+)

Which should break into 4 capturing groups -- in this case being

Installation - amma

domain - pr

service - app

node - 03

How would I mutate given the current capture groups?

I tried doing add field and then using the value in $1.

Does anyone have any advice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name your capture groups like this:

```
(?<field_name>pattern)
```

With this your grok pattern can look like this:

```
(?<installation>[^-]{4,5})-(?<domain>(pr|st))-(?<service>(app|svc|srv))-(?<node>(\d+))
```

Comment: As a question, does this apply to fields that filebeat adds in?  The hostname is not part of the log file itself, but is part of what filebeat is adding when the logs are sent.   From what I can tell my logstash config is matching on the "message" field and this field precedes that.

Comment: Any fields you manually or which are being automatically added with Filebeat should be accessible in your Logstash filter.

Comment: Cool, let me give it a test (someone just rebooted my VM, but your answer seems like it's dead on for what I need)

Comment: That didn't seem to work, I opened a new question over at:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211486/add-fields-to-logstash-based-off-of-filebeat-data