# Add fields to logstash based off of filebeat data

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-grok, grok, filebeat

So, I have a hostname that is being set by filebeat (and I've written a regex that should grab it), but the following isn't adding fields the way that I think it should..

```
grok{
  patterns_dir => "/config/patterns"
  match =>{ "beat.hostname" => ["%{INSTALLATION}-%{DOMAIN}-%{SERVICE}"] }
    add_field => { "[installation]" => "%{INSTALLATION}"}
    add_field => { "[domain]" => "%{DOMAIN}"}
    add_field => { "[service]" => "%{SERVICE}"}

 }
```

I can't seem to access beat.hostname, hostname, host or anything like that to add the fields that I want.  At present the hostname is: BOS-LAP-MYNAME1

Which should be matched by:

```
INSTALLATION [^-]{1,3}
DOMAIN (BOS|LAP)
SERVICE (MYNAME1|TEST|12345)
```

Also note:  I've tried the "host" "hostname" and other field names like that to no avail as well, despite those fields being available in Kibana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `hostname` is nested under `beat` you need to match against `[beat][hostname]` rather than `beat.hostname`. And to add those fields to the document use the form of `%{PATTERN:fieldname}` in the match parameter.

```
filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/config/patterns"]
    match => {
      "[beat][hostname]" => "%{INSTALLATION:installation}-%{DOMAIN:domain}-%{SERVICE:service}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: YOU GOOD SIR, ARE A BEAUTIFUL MAN <3